# Find matching values in 2 dataframes with different lengths in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm very new to R and I want to do something similar to a VLOOKUP to find matching values in 2 different dataframes and return a new dataframe with the matches. I would also like to get a sum of total matching values. **They are different lengths**. Not sure why but when I do an inner join, I get duplicates and there are no duplicates!
I used this function to remove dupes in both dataframes:
`df1[!duplicated(df1), ]`

I have tried this to return my dataframe with matching values:

`matches <- inner_join(df1, df2)`

Here is an example of my 2 tables and what I want to end up with:

df1:

| Column_Name |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |

df2:

| Column_Name |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |
| e |
| f |
| g |

What I want to be returned:
df3:

| Column_Name |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |

Thank you for any assistance here!

Comment: For the example you have shared `matches <- inner_join(df1, df2)` works as expected and returns a, b, c and d. Can you provide an example which actually reproduces the problem?

Comment: Yes, this seems to work: `df1 <- data.frame(column_name = letters[1:4]);   
df2 <- data.frame(column_name = letters[1:8]);   
inner_join(df1, df2)`

Answer (score 2):

I think `semi_join` is more appropriate in this situation:

`semi_join()`
return all rows from x **where there are matching values** in y, keeping just columns from x. A semi join differs from an inner join because an inner join will return one row of x for each matching row of y, where a semi join will never duplicate rows of x.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Column_Name=c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
df2 <- data.frame(Column_Name=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"))

df3 <- semi_join(df1, df2, by = "Column_Name")
```

Example:

```
# new values in df2
df2 <- data.frame(Column_Name=c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"))

# semi_join
df3 <- semi_join(df1, df2, by = "Column_Name")
# Output:
  Column_Name
1           a
2           b
3           c
4           d

# inner_join
df3 <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = "Column_Name")
# Output:
  Column_Name
1           a
2           a
3           b
4           c
5           c
6           d
```

Answer (score 0):

A Tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
# set your DataFrames, and then:
df1 %>% inner_join(df2, by='Column_Name')
```